# Can non-Muslims instill doubt to a believer?

Tags: discussion

More specifically can non-Muslims use this site to add comments to encourage doubts for those who haven't embraced Islam via rational proof of Allah or even low iman? Non-Muslims will always come from their interpretations of religion (the compromise that created secularism) and Islam. Thus always having the wrong premise for an Islamic discussion. Islam can never be compared side by side with any other ideology as the values are entirely different.

*O you who believe, do not take anyone as an insider but those from among your own selves. They would spare no effort to do you mischief. They want you to be in trouble. Malice has come out of their mouths while what is concealed in their hearts is still worse. We have made the signs clear to you, if only you understand. (118) Sural Al Imran.*

And Allah knows best.

Comment: a very valid concern , i have read several christian missionary articles wherein they describe various covert techniques like faking muslim identity and asking questions to create doubt , asking blasphemous questions etc. This hypocritical people have already caused a lot of damage to Muslims, history is witness.

Answer (score 8):

I keep saying this is not an "Islamic" website, it is an information website. We are not in a position to set the rules for this playground and censor questions that encourage doubt. If it were an Islamic website and we were in total control that might be something that could be done. Here however, it's an open playground, SE defines the skeleton system of rules, and everyone gets a voice as long as it falls within the rules.

The solution then, is to simply have convincing answers to those questions (making clear the different set of value systems).

Of course if there is really no question there, or it's not a real question, or it can't be answered, then it will be deleted as not meeting SE standards.

Answer (score 6):

I have always been *hostile* to the idea of shielding people from difficult questions. It is especially impossible in this age of free flowing information. Censoring critics only gives more validity to their claims. That being said, comments have a very limited scope as per SE guidelines. They are not debates (although I'm personally guilty of these from time to time) and should only concern themselves with the post being commented on. I can see some cases where comments can be used for trolling, but those should be judged on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 4):

As long as they abide to the same guidelines of referencing everything, I don't see why not. In fact, I'd almost encourage it. Muslims have a tendency to 'pat each other on the back' and overlook uncomfortable rulings, which can sometimes encourage biased interpretation and Bid'ah. I have learned more about Islam through non-believers than through many believers, just because they're willing to look harder for evidence, compared to many Muslims who just take things at face value.

Allowing anti-Islamic comments and answers should be allowed, and would encourage some proper academic debate, as long as it is not done with a hostile tone.

Comment: Im not talking about answers dude please read the question first! It says comment not answers. Who am I to disagree with the creator with the above ayah.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought by comments, you meant any kind of reply. I think it should be allowed every now and then, but if someone is consistently going around trolling comments by spreading misinformation where it can't be downvoted, then action should be taken, such as removing commenting privileges if that's possible. This should apply to Muslims who put misinformation in comments as well.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution to monitor that would be "flagging the comments" if you feel, they're really stupid. Based on

> O you who believe, do not take anyone as an insider but those from among your own selves. They would spare no effort to do you mischief. They want you to be in trouble. Malice has come out of their mouths while what is concealed in their hearts is still worse. We have made the signs clear to you, if only you understand. (118) Sural Al Imran.

But, if feel they're real and honest doubts worth answering, you can create a new question(if not already) and attract quality answers and showing that non believer the answer. By this, when you get the answers, in fact your Iman gets stronger and a possibility that doubter would start believing in Islam. After all, the non believer is asking you to answer his questions through that means. Now it is our responsibility to remain patient and answer him.

My example is "[Does Islam support pedophilia or child marriages?"](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/22982/does-islam-support-pedophilia-or-child-marriages?s=2%7C0.8756)